# How do I pass 2D array to the viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, swift5

I'm decoding the result and I wanted to send name and id to the viewcontroller. 
I just started to learn the JSON Codeable
So, how can I pass this data , I have declared the the 2 variables as an array.

```
var cityNames = [String]()
var cityNameId = [Int]()
for cityName in display.cities{
                            print(cityName.id , cityName.name)

                            self.cityNames.append(cityName.name)
                            self.cityNameId.append(cityName.id)
                        }
```

While printing I'm getting output

```
1 Mumbai
2 Pune
3 Thane
```

Expected result       `I'm want to display the names of the cities to the label in dropdown list of next viewController and  after selecting the city name from drop down ,.  I need the ID of that selected city for the button click event`

Comment: What is your expected result? What do you want to do with that result?

Comment: I'm want to display the names of the cities to the label in dropdown list of next viewController and  after selecting the city name from drop down ,.  I need the ID of that selected city for the button click event
 @MumtazHussain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a reference of next view controller (change the names of viewcontroller/storyboard/identifiers according to your requirements):

```
let nextVC = NextViewController()
```

or you can also instantiate from storyboard if you're using storyboards:

```
let nextVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
```

now pass whatever values you want to the nextVC as 2D array:

```
let cities2DArray = [cityNameId, cityNames] as [Any]
nextVC.cities2DArray = cities2DArray
```

You can do all the above work inside `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` if you're using segue with identifier, if not then simply do the work right before you're going to the nextVC programmatically.

Now, make sure you have these a 2DArray variables declared inside the `NextViewController`:

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {

    var cities2DArray = [Any]()
```

Updated:
In case you do want to make a tuple that has id and its corresponding name side by side in 1 array inside of tuple then you need to modify your for loop as following:

```
    var citiesTuple = [(id: Int, name: String)]()
    for cityName in display.cities{
        citiesTuple.append((id: cityName.id, name: cityName.name))
    }
```

Comment: I had already done this. I'm getting the 2 array values but want the combine result as above.

Comment: OK I'll try this

Comment: id is an Int and name is string

Comment: @PatelFab check now, both the parts.

Answer (score 1):

First create a structure for City as `Class` or `Struct`

```
class Context {
    let cities: [City]

    init(with cities: [City]) {
       self.cities = cities
    }
}
```

Than describe a variable as Context in your target view controller,

```
class TargetViewController: UIViewController{ 
 ...
 var context: Context?
}
```

Then if you push your viewController manually,

```
var targetController = TargetViewController()
targetController.context = Context(with: self.cities)
navigationController?.pushViewController(with: targetController)
```

or you can set it from storyboard with `prepareSegue` method.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "TargetSegueIdentifier") {
        var targetController = segue.destination as? TargetViewController
        targetController.context = Context(with: self.cities)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

Obviously `cities` represents an array of objects which contain both `name` and `id` information

Delete the arrays

```
var cityNames = [String]()
var cityNameId = [Int]()
```

Pass always the instance of the struct or class for example

```
if let firstCity = display.cities.first {
    print(firstCity.id , firstCity.name)
    // pass firstCity to next view controller
}
```

or

```
if let city = display.cities.first(where: {$0.name == "New York"}) {
    print(city.id , city.name)
    // pass city to next view controller
}
```

or in `didSelectRow` of a table view

```
let city = display.cities[indexPath.row]
// pass city to next view controller
```

Comment: ```if let firstCity = display.cities.first {
    print(firstCity.id , firstCity.name)
}``` I tried this but I what should I do if I want to retrieve the 3rd data..

Comment: I provided just a few examples. `cities` is an array, you can subscribe it by index (`display.cities[2]`) or use a loop.It depends on what you are going to accomplish.